# Forcing text to be UTF compliant using php iconv

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv

I am currently forcing data from a server to be UTF compliant by using the line of php:

```
$name = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $name);
```

This works flawlessly on my server running php 5.3, but not 5.4. (not sure if version is relevant). The server running 5.3 is unix, the server running 5.4 is ubuntu 12.04.

Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing something?

EDIT: Just to be clear:

$name before: Something — Subtitle

$name after on 5.3: Something

$name after on 5.4: null

Comment: I assume it is a problem with the underlying system's libc.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: try to execute `iconv` with sample data on the command line.. Does it work?